# Let $f \in L^2[0,\infty)$ be a continuous, positive and decreasing function, then $\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt{x}f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

[image]

Let $f \in L^2[0,\infty)$ be a continuous, positive and decreasing function, then $\lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt{x}f(x)=0$

This feels intuitively true but I am not sure how to prove it. I know that if $f$ is uniformly continuous then $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=0$ but I am not sure how to handle this. I am not sure how the hint is helpful.

Comment: There's a hint in the question. What happens if you take it?

Comment: @AnginaSeng I do not know how to calculate that integral. I know I can apply FTC but I do not know the antiderivative.

Comment: You can't "calculate" it, but can you say anything about it? You know already the integral $\int_0^\infty f^2(x)\,dx<\infty$...

Comment: Well, I can say it converges to 0 i guess.

Comment: This site is not there to solve your homework, show us at least what you tried ...

Comment: I would, if I knew where to start. The solution is a one liner. You either get it or you do not. I do not think much work can be shown here. Also it’s not homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_a^{2a}f(x)^2dx<\epsilon$ for $a$ large enough and $af(2a)^2 \le \int_a^{2a}f(x)^2dx$ because $f$ is decreasing.